# PHP in a embedded apache web server built with buildroot

Tags: apache-httpd, php, buildroot

So I built a embedded apache web server using buildroot, and it's is running fine except the fact that it doesn't run php code.
I can run .php files in the command line of the system but when I open those .php files in a browser it doesn't run the php code, it simply ignores all php code and interprets it like if it was html.

I looked in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file and it has a line loading the php module:

```
LoadModule php7_module     modules/libphp7.so
```

Does anyone knows how to make php run?

I will leave, just in case, information about some directories and files that might be relevant:

/etc/

- apache2/
- php-fpm.conf
- php-fpm.d/
- php.ini

/etc/apache2/

- extra/
- httpd.conf.bak
- mime.types
- httpd.conf
- magic
- original/

/usr/lib/php/

- (empty)

/usr/modules/libphp7.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to loading the module (which your httpd.conf file shows it is doing based on the content of your question) you also need to use a `SetHandler` directive for `*.php` or other appropriate extensions.

Something like this should work, just put it right after the `LoadModule` statement.

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

What this above statement does it is tells Apache how to deal with files with certain extensions.   The `.+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$` is a regular expression (regex) that matches several different endings for the file (the `$` indicates end of the string) - so files ending in `.php`, `.php3`, `.php4`, etc. will all get processed by the Apache server and PHP module before being sent to the browser.

Don't forget to restart the httpd service.

If it still doesn't work, check the paths referencing the module to load and make sure the `libphp7.so` is in the right location to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can you just explain me what the <FilesMatch ".....$"> statement does? I tried with and without it and it worked both ways.

Comment: @M_Luis - I've edited the answer to include more info on it